# mybatis query doesnt work well

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Dto">
   INSERT INTO table VALUES
    (GeomFromText('POINT(#{latitude} #{longitude})'))
</insert>
```

I would like to execute above query, however it returns some error

> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (12 >
>   number of parameters, which is 11).

```
INSERT INTO filtered_user_location VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'))
```

I think the error means that prepared statement(?) in a single quotation doesn't work.

do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx Mr.Alien for edit

I fixed query like

> GeomFromText('POINT(${latitude} ${longitude})')

then it works well

Answer (score 0):

In read out with this tutorial,

http://mybatis.co.uk/

Its seems to do somthing like this. You dint mention any column name in your query.

```
insert into filtered_user_location 
 (columnname1,columnname2) 
VALUES  
 (#{latitude},#{longitude});
```